# Is intercepting TCP/IP traffic easy if i use RC4 SSL Cipher suites?

Tags: ssl, encryption, tcp

I am having a server which supports RC4 SSL Cipher suites. I just want to know whether it is easy for a attacker to determine the contents and IP of the users who are connecting to my server?

Comment: Determining the IP address is trivial. Each IP packet contains it in its header. SSL doesn't even attempt to hide it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks for the info. So what does SSL Cipher suites hide?

Comment: The content of the communication.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Please post it as answer. This information might help others also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Concerning the IP, that is out of scope for SSL. SSL works on top of TCP and thus doesn't even know about IPs. Hiding IPs is hard, since they're required to deliver data to the correct recipient. You can use proxies like TOR to hide your IP.
2. SSL keeps the content transferred over the encrypted connection secret. RC4 isn't the greatest encryption since it produces a biased bitstream. That allows an attacker to learn your secret data if it's transferred *several billion times* at a known position close the the beginning of the stream.